# why doesn't the server pick up the path i give it in the image tag?

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish

I am using glassfish. on a jsp page when i write :

```
<img src="/home/non-admin/project users/pic.jpg"/>
```

the IDE highlights the line with an error saying this is a bad value. But when i give the path( to the same image) from the directory inside the project it picks it up and displays the image. Like `project/images/pic.jpg`  Why doesn't it pick up just any path from my system. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It can't pick up any path of your system (Imagine some one is reading your system's file by just accessing path in their browser :) ), You need to write a Servlet which will read that file from your system and write to output in response

Comment: Sure, Basically your servlet needs to read the file located from your file system and write the content to response and set headers accordingly, See this [nice article](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because it is based on the path to the base of the webpage, which is usually something like /var/www/htdocs To allow something in a homedirectory you can create a link to that directory from within the web directory something like `ln -s /home/non-admin/project\ users/ /var/www/htdocs/userdata` then use `<img src="/userdata/pic.jpg"/>`. Also you need to set the permissions on the directory/file to allow the www user to read it.